# Eclipse not showing Java 9 options

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9

I downloaded the [last Oxygen (3A) package from March 18'](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/Oxygen/3A) in order to trying Java 9. Using [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/13630/javase9-helloworld-module-ides-part4), I was trying to get a grasp on the module.

However, in this tutorial, there is a checkbox that I do not have, while adding a source folder to a Java project:

> [X] Create module-info.java (9 or higher)

I tried to get some patch on [Java 9 compatibility for Eclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-oxygen), but failed. Indeed, on this page, the following message is shown to the user:

> Note: This feature patch is disabled. It was originally intended to be installed on top of 4.7.1 builds.

The `Help > About Eclipse` window displays the following info:

> Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

However, it seems that it is not the case. I already installed a JDK 9 on my computer, and set those lines in my `eclipse.ini` file:

> -vm
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\javaw.exe
>
> -vmargs
>
> --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

So Eclipse should run with Java 9 and give me the right options.

---

Am I missing something ? It looks not logical to me that they would remove this kind of checkbox.

Comment: *"Am I missing something?"* Yes, those instructions are for Eclipse Oxygen M4, but you're running Eclipse Oxygen.3a, i.e. not the same version, so don't expect dialogs to be exactly the same. Also, you might be running the EE version of Eclipse, while tutorial may have used a barebones version, because the even the previous "Create a Java Project" dialog doesn't look like that, and hasn't for ages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like that option actually made it in to the Eclise Oxygen final releases. According to bug report [525374](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525374) it should be in Eclipse Photon (4.8).

You can create the module-info.java by right clicking on the Project and selecting 'Configure > Create module-info.java'.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll do it from now on